# Pandas groupby and weighted sum for multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by, pandas-groupby

I've see a dozen Pandas groupby multiple columns questions, but I'm at a loss on how to get this to run in a reasonable time.  My goal is to groupby a few columns, and with the resulting subset  apply `np.dot` across each remaining column against my weights:

```py
# Example data:
weights = np.array([.20, .60, .20])
data = pd.DataFrame([[0, "TX", 10, 55], [0, "TX", 5, 30], [0, "TX", 2, 75], [1, "TX", 4, 30], [1, "TX", 8, 100], [1, "TX", 2, 30]], columns=["sim", "state", "x1", "x2"])

print(data)
   sim state  x1   x2
0    0    TX  10   55
1    0    TX   5   30
2    0    TX   2   75
3    1    TX   4   30
4    1    TX   8  100
5    1    TX   2   30
```

I couldn't get `np.dot` to work out of the box, so I had to break the multiplication and summation into separate steps. Here's what i've tried, but on my dataset of a few million rows this takes ~2 minutes, not to mention being pretty unreadable:

```py
results = data.groupby(["sim", "state"]).apply(lambda sdf: (sdf[["x1", "x2"]] * weights.reshape((3,1))).sum())

print(results.reset_index())
   sim state   x1    x2
0    0    TX  5.4  44.0
1    1    TX  6.0  72.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about...

```
(df.set_index(['sim', 'state'])
   .mul(np.tile(weights, len(df) // len(weights)), axis=0)
   .sum(level=[0, 1]))

            x1    x2
sim state           
0   TX     5.4  44.0
1   TX     6.0  72.0
```

How this works,

- set the index to whatever should not be multiplied (`df`'s primary keys, essentially)
- use `mul` to perform broadcasted multiplication with the weights
- group on the indices and sum the weighted values.

This works under the assumption that `len(df) % len(weights) == 0`.

Comment: Do you mean the `len(df.groupby([...]) % len(weights) == 0`?  In my real data I have 10k simulations where each grouping is the same length as my weights.

Comment: @Tony essentially each group should have a <multiple of len(weights)> rows, yes. Assuming you have only one set of weights. If you have multiple weights, for each group, you can concat them to one (ensure the concated result length is equal to len(df)) instead of tiling.